# Kotlin, Intent: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, alert

**Intent doesn't work with RestApiService callback.**

Previously It worked in RegisterActivity:

```
fun alert(text: String) {
    val intent = Intent(this, PopUp::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("text", text)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I want to display the result as a pop-up message. `PopUp` is a custom activity view.

When I place it into another class, there is an error:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments

> supplied. (Context!, Class<*>!) defined in

> android.content.Intent (String!, Uri!) defined in

> android.content.Intent

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class RestApiService {

// MY CUSTOM INTENT! WORKED BEFORE IF TO PLACE INTO AN ACTIVITY.
fun alert(text: String) {
    val intent = Intent(this, PopUp::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("text", text)
    startActivity(intent)
}

fun addUser(userData: ModelUserRegister, onResult: (ModelUserRegister?) -> Unit){
    val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApi::class.java)
    retrofit.addUser(userData).enqueue(

        object : Callback<ModelUserRegister> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ModelUserRegister>, t: Throwable) {
                onResult(null)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ModelUserRegister>, response: Response<ModelUserRegister>) {
                val addedUser = response.body()
                if (response.code() in 200..320)
                {
                    alert(response.message())
                } else {
                    alert(response.message())
                }
                onResult(addedUser)
            }
        }
    )
}
}
```

The latest research gave me the advice to change:

```
val intent = Intent(this, PopUp::class.java)
```

to:

```
val intent = Intent(RegisterActivity.this, PopUp::class.java)
```

Didn't help. This question for those people who want to use **Kotlin**!

Comment: Do you understand what `this` means? The first argument of the Intent constructor is a Context. Also, you can't call `startActivity` out of nowhere. It is a function of Context. `this` and `startActivity()` work when your code is in an Activity because Activity *is* a Context. `RegisterActivity.this` is for the situation where you are creating the intent inside a callback and in Kotlin would be `this@RegisterActivity`. But that's not the problem you have here.

Answer (score 4):

To create a new Intent object, you have to pass `context` as the first parameter. You cannot just use `this` anywhere since depending on where you use it, it might not be `context`.

You can use `this` or `this@ActivityName` (`ActivityName.this` in Java) only when your codes are in an activity.

You can add a `context` parameter to your `alert()` function to fix this issue:

```
fun alert(context: Context, text: String) {
    val intent = Intent(context, PopUp::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("text", text)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it is the same one I've described first. Just **this** instead of **context**. That is the point: "only when your codes are in an activity".
How can I send a callback text for example and call the alert? In IOS there is a class for active View Controller ...

Answer (score 0):

**Step1.** Considering an absence of information the easiest solution is to use `callback` or `return` value *(String? in my case).*

```
class RestApiService {

    fun addUser(userData: ModelUserRegister, onResult: (ModelUserRegister?, String?)-> Unit){
        //... code
        onResult(addedUser, response.message())
    }
}
```

**Step2.** Call the returned value from the main `Activity` and use an `Intent` with alert `View`

```
apiService.addUser(userInfo) { modelUserRegister: ModelUserRegister?, s: String? ->
    if (s != null) {
        alert(s)
    } else {
        alert("NO TEXT AS A RESULT")
    }
}
```

Still waiting for any suggestions to call the Intent outside the `Activity class`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one, if from a fragment:

```
val intent = Intent(requireContext, PopUp::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `applicationContext` instead. There are three contexts an intent or toast will accept. They are `applicationContext`, `requireContext`, or `this`.

Your code should look like this:

```
val intent = Intent(application Context, Second activity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```